# How to create a recurrent payment with varying amount each month with paypal?

Tags: paypal, payment, credit-card

I'm trying to create a "subscription plan" with varying amount with paypal, only accepting credit card and paypal. And I want the UI to look like the one in Grooveshark.com when you choose to upgrade to Grooveshark anywhere, except that the plan isn't fixed. How do I do that using the paypal API?

My goal is that my website should draw a varying amount each month from my clients's credit card. (Like my Amazon AWS account).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paypal Reference Transactions