# Is it possible to create an automatic payment solution with varying sums?

Tags: payment, pci-dss

There are many payment processors that handle recurring payments and subscriptions with a fixed amount for each time period. I am looking to implement a solution similar to Google Apps or Amazon AWS where you are instead automatically billed a different amount each month to your credit card.

I know this can be achieved by using [PayPal Reference Transactions](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECReferenceTxns), but for several reasons I would like to avoid PayPal  (bad checkout flow and a history of suspending accounts).

Are there any other online payment systems that provide this functionality for credit cards? Preferably it should be able to be integrated directly with good developer resources and pci-dss compliance (such as [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/)) that I like a lot.

A related question has been answered before ([How to create a recurrent payment with varying amount each month with paypal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408603/how-to-create-a-recurrent-payment-with-varying-amount-each-month-with-paypal)) but that was explicitly asking for a PayPal solution which I don't want.

Comment: Stripe offer it (see Metered Billing) https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for. If you submit it as an answer I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe offer it (see Metered Billing) at [stripe.com/docs/subscriptions](http://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions).

*ecommerce continuous authority* would be another good google-able phrase for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is comment worthy, but I don't have enough SO street cred yet. Check out http://www.cybersource.com . They are very robust and offer a lot of flexibility versus other vendors.

The way most payment vendors that I have worked with are similar in the way that you can register a recurring payment account with a max payment amount.  You could register the account with a high payment amount.

Another possibility is to update the recurring payment account to accept the new sum for that month. Are there any type of event or trigger that occurs when the sum on a payment changes?

Comment: Thanks. The total sum to be billed is based on usage, so at the end of the month the total usage of different services for that month will be summed up and hopefully billed automatically. One way to go would be to save credits on the site and automatically bill a fixed amount whenever the credits go under this threshold. But as I stated in the original question I would preferably find a system that can bill Amazon AWS style.